# shell unexpected end of file error

Tags: shell, shell-script

I had the below script working in a linux machine.

```
page="$(curl http://www.google.com/| grep "title")"
if [ -z "$page" ]; then
echo "Empty page"
else
echo "Valid page"
fi
```

When am running in another machine, I am getting the error **syntax error: unexpected end of file**. Why am getting this error?

Comment: What are the machines? You have to watch for differences in the various shells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have invisible CR characters at the end of your lines (like when the file is in Microsoft format where the lines are terminated by the CRLF sequence of characters instead of just LF).

Then, the shell complains that it reaches the end of the script file without finding a `then` following the `if` (there's just a `then<CR>`).

Use `dos2unix` or `d2u`, or issue a `:set ff=unix` in `vim` to fix your script file.